# R - Finance back test function for entry / exit signal

Tags: r

Ok so I am back testing trading signals using R. Here is a snippet of my code which shows the z-score creation, close to close returns (using TTR package), the long signal and the Lag() to place the signal the next day.

```
require(quantmod)
require(TTR)
require(zoo)

 # Calculate n period close price z-scores indicator using TTR package
    new.df$roll.mean.n3 <- runMean(new.df$Close, n=3, cumulative = FALSE)
    new.df$roll.sd.n3 <- runSD(new.df$Close, n=3, cumulative = FALSE)
    new.df$roll.z.score.n3 <- apply(new.df[,c('Close','roll.mean.n3', 'roll.sd.n3')], 1, function(x) { (x[1]-x[2])/x[3] } )

# Calculate Close-to-Close returns

    new.df$clret <- ROC(new.df$Close,1)
    new.df$clret[1] <- 0

# Create the long (up) signal 

    new.df$sigup <- ifelse(new.df$roll.z.score.n3 < -1, 1, 0) 

# Lag signals to align with days in market not days when signals were generated

    new.df$sigup <- Lag(new.df$sigup,1) # Note k=1 implies a move *forward*
```

The current setup above produces an output like this :

```
    roll.z.score.n3 sigup
1      NA           0
2      NA           0
3   -1.135974424    0
4   0.193311168     1
5   0.714285714     0
6   -1.148753543    0
7   -0.942160394    1
8   -0.695763683    0
9   1.140646864     0
10  0.985196899     0
11  -0.768766574    0
12  -1.011293858    0
13  -0.516703612    1
14  -1.120897077    0
15  1.091089451     1
```

The entry signal is to go long when zscore value is <-1 which is shown in row 3. We have a +1 on row 4 because we used Lag() to forward step the entry signal to the next day. Each time the z-score value is below -1, there is a +1 the next day.

This setup is perfectly fine if i'm only trading for 1 holding day only.

I can then multiply sigup 1 x % daily returns to obtain an equity curve.

I want to elaborate further on the entry / exit signals. I wish to go long (sig long) when zscore is <-1 and exit when z-score is >1.

The output would look something like this:

```
    roll.z.score.n3 sig long    
1           NA          0          
2           NA          0          
3   -1.135974424        0          
4   0.193311168         1          
5   0.714285714         1          
6   -1.148753543        1          
7   -0.942160394        1          
8   -0.695763683        1          
9   1.140646864         1          
10  0.985196899         0          
11  -0.768766574        0          
12  -1.011293858        0          
13  -0.516703612        1          
14  -1.120897077        1          
15  1.091089451         1          
16  0.968364052         0          
17  0.872871561         0          
18  1.099524999         0          
19  0.918397948         0
```

Row 3 shows a zscore signal of <-1. Lag next day makes it +1 (row 4). And it stays +1 all way until row 9 when z-score signal is >1.0. Thus, the next day at row 10, the signal is 0.

I wanted to give some background on the current coding, its an attempt to further the [post](http://blog.fosstrading.com/2009/04/testing-rsi2-with-r.html) at FOSS trading blog.

Thanks for taking a look at this.

Comment: Why your signal is not zero when `row 9` is `1.140646864`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that in my output example

Comment: where are you getting your `Lag` function from?

Comment: quantmod / TTR / zoo are required packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following works:

```
zz = '
    roll.z.score.n3 sig_long    
1           NA          0          
2           NA          0          
3   -1.135974424        0          
4   0.193311168         1          
5   0.714285714         1          
6   -1.148753543        1          
7   -0.942160394        1          
8   -0.695763683        1          
9   1.140646864         1          
10  0.985196899         0          
11  -0.768766574        0          
12  -1.011293858        0          
13  -0.516703612        1          
14  -1.120897077        1          
15  1.091089451         1          
16  0.968364052         0          
17  0.872871561         0          
18  1.099524999         0          
19  0.918397948         0   
'

df <- read.table(text = zz, header = TRUE)
df = na.omit(df)

df$sig_long[[1]] = ifelse(df$roll.z.score.n3[[1]] < (-1), 1, 0)

for (i in 2:nrow(df)){
  df$sig_long[i] = ifelse(df$roll.z.score.n3[i] < (-1), 1,
                          ifelse(df$roll.z.score.n3[i] > 1, 0,
                                 df$sig_long[i-1]))
}
```

Not sure about this part:

```
df$sig_long <- Lag(df$sig_long, 1)
```

Comment: Yes if we can bump the whole output +1 day it would be perfect. This is what Lag() did originally.

Comment: have you tried this part: `df$sig_long <- Lag(df$sig_long, 1)`

Comment: Hi AK88 - Do you think I can edit the exit so that the loop stops after a set number of nlines. I can make a nline variable. And then once the loop starts, it exits after nline number has been met. This way if i set nlines <- 5. I can make it go 1,1,1,1,1 for total 5 lines. Or I can set nlines <- 20 and the loop will stop at +line 20 from the exit.

Comment: Hey, I think you can do that. Let me take a look.

Comment: Hmmm, its a bit complicated.  If on day `n` your score is less than `-1` but the total number of `n` long days is `n`, do you want to to close the position or stay long?

Comment: Yes - Close the position when the n long days is exceed. So we only hold have 1,s during the nline period, so if hold for 5 lines, then we have 1's for 5 lines after entry. We are basically ignoring the fixed value for exit. We take the entry as per -1, and exit nlines later.

Comment: I was thinking.... perhaps rather than incorporating the nline exit condition in the loop. What if, at the end of the loop, we can do a subtraction of the start of the loop - end of loop, if that nrow value is > the nlines, replace the +1s with 0

Comment: I completely forgot about this issue, sorry. Maybe you can create a new topic?

Comment: Ok try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876835/r-end-a-loop-on-a-fixed-number-of-rows