# R - End a loop on a fixed number of rows

Tags: r

I have a loop that begins when a certain condition exits. It begins when the value is below  -.1.0 The loop exits when the condition is over 1.0

```
    #Loop for long entry and exit signal 
    entry <- -1.0     #Input value for entry
    exit <- 1.o       #Input value for exit


mydf$sig_long[[1]] = ifelse(mydf$roll.z.score.n3[[1]] < (entry), 1, 0)

    for (i in 2:nrow(mydf)){
      mydf$sig_long[i] = ifelse(mydf$roll.z.score.n3[i] < (entry), 1,
                              ifelse(mydf$roll.z.score.n3[i] > (exit), 0,
                              mydf$sig_long[i-1]))
    }
```

I wanted to learn how to use the same loop but instead of exit on values > 1.0 Exit after a set number of lines. If for example I set nline variable to 5. It would loop and print 1, for a total of 5 lines after the initial entry. An example data frame below:

```
    roll.z.score.n3
1   0
2   0
3   0.651651537
4   -1.153593891
5   -0.926552368
6   -0.369016769
7   0.65405595
8   -1.139305279
9   0.358231351
10  1.135314685
11  0.944997472
12  -0.293105191
13  -1.146659778
14  -0.66246734
15  -1.131901741
16  -0.600480649
17  -1.152333435
18  1.1025176
19  -0.144684006
20  -0.678000883
21  -1.146875039
22  -1.132235788
23  0.115583229
24  0.645489447
25  1.148754398
26  0.988193418
27  -0.818892395
```

After the script has run I would use zoo to +1 line the sig_long column.

```
  new.df$sig_long <- Lag(new.df$sig_long,1)
```

### Code Testing

Ok so i see the issue. As we are specifying the first part of the loop to enter and exit between -1.0 and 1.0 this prints 1's between those two criteria in the new.df$sig_long column. The issue arises if I set the nlines to 5. The entry/exit might exit the trade in 3 lines in the sig_long column. If that is the case, rollsum has no 1's to count in that column, even if i want to hold for 5 lines, if theres only 3 1's from entry... its not going to be able to compute the 5 line hold time. Perhaps we can use the first part of the loop like this in order to print a 1 at the entry condition:

```
new.df$sig_long <- ifelse(new.df$roll.z.score.n3 < -1.0 , 1, 0) #Set 1 at entry criteria
```

That sets the 1 at each < -1.0 value. Next would be how to count +5 lines from that point forward. Counting until...1,2,3,4,5, else 0... 0, until next +1.... count until 1,2,3,4,5, else 0, 0 until next +1....

I can see the logic... if newdf$sig_long == 1, count until nlines 5, else 0, repeat...

Then the 2nd part of the loop would work I think for the new_sig_long column

Comment: `?while` is what you are looking for

Comment: mydf$sig_long[[1]] = ifelse(mydf$ADT5[[1]] < (entry), 1, 0)

    for (i in 2:nrow(mydf)){
      mydf$sig_long[i] = ifelse(mydf$ADT5[i] < (entry), 1,
                              while(nrow[i] < (nlines), 1,
                              mydf$sig_long[i-1]))
    }

Answer (score 0):

Made many changes. This should now work:

```
zz = '
    roll.z.score.n3 sig_long    
1           NA          0          
2           NA          0          
3   -1.135974424        0          
4   0.193311168         1          
5   0.714285714         1          
6   -1.148753543        1          
7   -0.942160394        1          
8   -0.695763683        1          
9   1.140646864         1          
10  0.985196899         0          
11  -0.768766574        0          
12  -1.011293858        0          
13  -0.516703612        1          
14  -1.120897077        1          
15  1.091089451         1          
16  0.968364052         0          
17  0.872871561         0          
18  1.099524999         0          
19  0.918397948         0   
'

df <- read.table(text = zz, header = TRUE)
df = na.omit(df)

df$sig_long[[1]] = ifelse(df$roll.z.score.n3[[1]] < (-1), 1, 0)

for (i in 2:nrow(df)){
  df$sig_long[i] = ifelse(df$roll.z.score.n3[i] < (-1), 1,
                          ifelse(df$roll.z.score.n3[i] > 1, 0,
                                 df$sig_long[i-1]))
}

df$sig_long <- Lag(df$sig_long, 1)
colnames(df[, 2]) = "sig_long"

df = na.omit(df)
nlines = 5

df$rollsum = rollsumr(df$sig_long, k = nlines, fill = 0)
colnames(df[, 3]) = "rollsum"
df$new_sig_long[[1]] = ifelse(df$roll.z.score.n3[[1]] < (-1), 1, 0)

for (i in 2:nrow(df)){
  df$new_sig_long[i] = ifelse(df$roll.z.score.n3[i] < (-1) & df$rollsum[i] < 5, 1,
                              ifelse(df$roll.z.score.n3[i] > 1 | df$rollsum[i] >= 5, 0,
                                     df$sig_long[i-1]))
}

df
```

Output:

```
    > df
       roll.z.score.n3 sig_long rollsum new_sig_long
  #  4        0.1933112        1       0            0
  #  5        0.7142857        1       0            1
  #  6       -1.1487535        1       0            1
  #  7       -0.9421604        1       0            1
  #  8       -0.6957637        1       5            0
  #  9        1.1406469        1       5            0
  #  10       0.9851969        0       4            1
  #  11      -0.7687666        0       3            0
  #  12      -1.0112939        0       2            1
  #  13      -0.5167036        1       2            0
  #  14      -1.1208971        1       2            1
  #  15       1.0910895        1       3            0
  #  16       0.9683641        0       3            1
  #  17       0.8728716        0       3            0
  #  18       1.0995250        0       2            0
  #  19       0.9183979        0       1            0
```

Then you can take the `lag` of the `new_sig_long` if you wish.

Comment: I guess we are trying to count the sig_long... i received this error...> new.df$rollsum = rollsumr(new.df$sig_long, k = 5, fill = 0)
Error: k <= n is not TRUE

Comment: did that code above work ok on your end? Thanks, Andrew

Comment: Edited the entire reply

Comment: Its close - the logic seems right to me - however i see the results are not quite as intended. See my edit, thanks